# How to check SharePoint Online site type

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, modern-experience, communication-site

I am using SharePoint Online and have an existing site.
It is most likely communication or publishing.

How to check, which type it is?

Is it possible to do so from the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint Online Management Shell to run a PowerShell cmdlet to get the template id and compare to known site template values:

```
$adminUPN=<admin account>
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://domainname-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
Get-SPOSite -Identity <site url> -detailed | Select template
```

This will return a template ID and you can refer to a list of site templates here:
https://vladtalkstech.com/2019/12/sharepoint-online-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html

Note: this will only work for top-level sites/site collections, not subsites, and will return an error if you include an ending forward slash.

Comment: Thank you :)  
Is there a way to check it from the browser?

Comment: @Ania, communication site is a modern site with a unique Layout, you can check it here:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-sharepoint-communication-site-94a33429-e580-45c3-a090-5512a8070732  If you are an admin, go SharePoint Admin center>Active sites, find your site and you will know if it is a communication site.

Comment: @Ania https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-sites-in-new-admin-center Please follow this tutorial to start with new admin center